# Copy files from AWS S3 when building war file on elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am looking to copy a file from s3 bucket `ls-Bucket` to my EC2 in  `/tmp/` folder. I want to do this when i upload my war file to elastic beanstalk and hit deploy.

here is my config file for `.ebextentions`  folder `setup.conf`

```
container_commands:
# Copy script from s3-bucket to PATH: /tmp/myFile.txt
01-copyFromS3ToTmp:
 files:
 "/tmp/myFile.txt":
 source: https://ls-Busket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myFile.txt
 authentication: S3Access

Resources:
 AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
  Metadata:
   AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
    S3Access:
     type: S3
     roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
     buckets: ls-Busket
```

I use the upload and deploy using Elastic Beanstalk and everything is OK (Health)
but when I SSH into my instance and check the tmp folder I can't see my file and can't see any ERRORs
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated, new to AWS.

Thanks in advance

G

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Your method of file creation is not quite right.

Try this:

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
       AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Access:
         type: S3
         roleName: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
         buckets: ["ls-Busket"]
  files:
    "/tmp/myFile.txt":
      source: https://ls-Busket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/myFile.txt
      authentication: S3Access
```